# Show Results' line numbers using grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, formatting, line

how i can show the result of my grep command with incremental numbers before them ,
i'm not talking about using -n or -nr to show where is my string located in that files.
i'm talking about something like this :

```
 grep foo *.*
```

result should be like this :

> **1**-file12.txt:   ....foo..... 
>   **2**-file52.txt:   ....foo.....
>   **3**-file87.txt:   ....foo...
>   .
>   .

Thanks

Comment: Grep won't do it on its own but you could surely write a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it through `nl`, the dedicated "number lines" tool:

```
grep foo * | nl
```

This obviously works for all commands, and not just `grep`.

Comment: `cat -n` appears to be widely supported (GNU, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris), but it's not present in Busybox or POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

This awk can handle it in single command:

```
awk '/foo/{printf "%d-%s:\t%s\n", (++i), FILENAME, $0}' *.*
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i really didn't care that much about the '-' between the number and the result . :)
thanks

Comment: Oh `-` was just for formatting, not really important for this command.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overdoing it but you can at least try it:

```
n=0
for item in $(grep foo *)
do
    n=$((n+1))
    echo "$n-$item"
done
```

In one line:

```
n=0;for item in $(grep foo *); do n=$((n+1)); echo "$n-$item"; done
```

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop to iterate over **lines** unless you set `IFS=$'\n'` -- `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$((++n))-$line"; done`

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i really didn't care that much about the '-' between the number and the result . :)
thanks